# Changing the Input Language to default when form deactivates

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have a form, it uses a certain Input Language , when i switch to another window like a browser I want to change back to the computers default Input Language ,  seems simple. Just use the form deactivate event and put

```
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.DefaultInputLanguage;
```

Doesn't work.  The deactivate event only triggers after the form has been deactivated but the system Input Language  cannot be changed unless your form has focus.

I need an event that triggers right before a form deactivates to run that line of code. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The obvious solution would be the `LostFocus` event, but this seems like poor design to have gotten yourself into this situation in the first place.

Comment: @CodyGray This event only works for Controls on a form,  not the whole form itself.  And how is it poor design?

Comment: Hmm, they've hidden `LostFocus` for the Form class? I couldn't remember. What you want is the low-level `WM_KILLFOCUS` message, it is sent before the window actually loses the focus. This may not be exposed in WinForms. The strange part of the design is that you're changing the current thread's input language. Why should you need to change it back? Your change isn't going to propagate to IE or whatever; it runs in a different thread.

Comment: @CodyGray no this isn't correct.  Windows 10 uses a single input language setting globally.  Changing the input language in my form will change it for all applications.

Comment: Huh, you're right. Looks like that did change in Windows 10. There is now a setting you can enable to allow each app to have its own language, which appears to be off by default. I had no idea this had changed. It seems completely broken to me. A thread should not be able to change the *global* state so easily. Oh well, sorry I can't help. You clearly know more about this than I do!